# How to iterate over a column of a data frame in pandas, column cannot be selected by number

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

I am new to python/pandas and am trying to loop through a column of a data frame and print all US State abbreviations (in order to get data from Quandl). I do not know why I cannot select columns by number and the for loop will not iterate over the column by name.

`fifty_states` a list of data frames, and `fifty_states[0]` is the specific data frame I want (50 rows x 13 columns). `print(fifty_states[0]['Abbreviation'])` gives the column I am interested in, but my for loop must be flawed because it only returns 'FMAC/HPI_Abbreviation'.

```
fifty_states=pd.read_html('https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states')

for abbv in fifty_states[0]['Abbreviation']:
   print("FMAC/HPI_"+str(abbv))
```

I have tried referencing the column by number, i.e. `fifty_states[0][0]`, but no matter the column number, a KeyError of the column number I tried is returned, for instance it would say 'KeyError: 0' here.

I am expecting an output with 50 rows like this:

```
FMAC/HPI_AL
FMAC/HPI_AK 
FMAC/HPI_AR
...
FMAC/HPI_WV
FMAC/HPI_WY
```

Comment: Looks like you have a multiindex there. You can try to access the values instead with: `fifty_states[0]['Abbreviation'].values`. But I don't know if that fits into your solution. Here is how you figure it out: `print(fifty_states[0].columns)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should add `header = 0` to read_html. This will tell pandas to read the first line as the column labels for the DataFrame. Without doing this the DataFrame column won't be labeled 'Abbreviation', which is why you're getting a key error. If you give pd.read_html the header argument you will be able to use the rest of your code without alteration.

```
fifty_states=pd.read_html('https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states', header=0)

for abbv in fifty_states[0]['Abbreviation']:
   print("FMAC/HPI_"+str(abbv))
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked :)
I also solved it by being more scrupulous with my syntax:
```
for abbv in fifty_states[0][fifty_states[0].columns[1]]:
    print("FMAC/HPI_"+str(abbv))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in fifty_states[0].iteritems():
    print(row)
```

Although iterating over a dataframe is a bad idea as people is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate on your column with a for loop :

```
for i in fifty_states['Abbreviation']:
    print(i)
```